# How to change the total from select option with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have table with default amount and pre-number select option on top. When select a new price will change in each row's input. Here I want the new number from select calculate the total price into the next row automatically.

```js
$('select.set_price').change(function() {
  var pset = $(this).data('pset');
  $('td.' + pset).find('input.price').val($(this).val());
});
//calc
$('.price').keyup(function() {
  var i_pay = $(this).closest('tr').find('#pay').text();
  var i_bet = $(this).val();
  var total = (i_pay * i_bet);
  $(this).closest('tr').find('#pay').html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="align-middle text-center">#</th>
    <th>
      <select class="form-select set_price" data-pset="p_3hi">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Order</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">1</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_3hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" name="price1" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">
      <p id="pay">900</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">2</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_3hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" name="price2" value="1" /></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">
      <p id="pay">800</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I expect is when I select `5`. The #1 row's total would be `5*900=4500` and the #2 would be `5*800=4000`. Please find the fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/w56940ez/

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. And since you only have the keyup event bound to the input, trigger the keyup event on the input when you change the select element.

Comment: I change `#pay` to `.pay` and `.keyup` into `on.('keyup change',`. But still not working. https://jsfiddle.net/w56940ez/2/

Comment: No, you don't need to also add the change event (although that could work), but rather add `$('.price').trigger('keyup')` at the end of your select's change event handler function

Comment: I got select change working now but another problem is. Type in is not calculate. I did `$('td.' + pset).find('input.price').val($(this).val()).trigger('keyup');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change `$('.price').keyup(function(){});` to `$('.price').change(function(){});` or you won't be able to change total value using arrows. If you don't want to use arrows you can keep keyup event.

To automatically change the value of the `total` column you just need to use `trigger("change")` on your ìnput elements.

If you want the base values to always be 800 and 900, you should use a data-attributes (`data-first-value`) which will keep this value and which will be used during the calculation.

Identifiers must be unique like @j08691 said. So you have basically two solutions:

- use a `pay` class instead of a `pay` id. You juste need to replace `id="pay"` with `class="pay"` and `#pay` with `.pay`
- use two identifiers. You need to add another data-attributes (`data-id`) and use it to get the input you want.

```js
$('select.set_price').change(function() {
  var pset = $(this).data('pset');
  input_elements = $('td.' + pset).find('input.price');
  input_elements.val($(this).val());
  input_elements.trigger("change");
});
//calc
$('.price').change(function() {
  /*
  USING A CLASS FOR BOTH 
  
  var i_pay = $(this).closest('tr').find('.pay').attr("data-first-val");
  var i_bet = $(this).val();
  var total = (i_pay * i_bet);
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.pay').html(total);
  
  */
  
  var i_pay = $("#"+$(this).attr("data-id")).attr("data-first-val");
  var i_bet = $(this).val();
  var total = (i_pay * i_bet);
  $("#"+$(this).attr("data-id")).html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="align-middle text-center">#</th>
    <th>
      <select class="form-select set_price" data-pset="p_3hi">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Order</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">1</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_3hi">
    <input type="number" class="form-control price" name="price1" value="1" data-id="pay_1" />
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">
    <p id="pay_1" data-first-val="900">900</p>
      <!--<p class="pay" data-first-val="900">900</p>-->
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">2</td>
    <td class="w-10 p_3hi"><input type="number" class="form-control price" name="price2" value="1" data-id="pay_2"/></td>
    <td class="align-middle text-center">
    <p id="pay_2" data-first-val="800">800</p>
      <!--<p class="pay" data-first-val="800">800</p>-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```